# How to split a tuple using train_test_split?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, train-test-split

```
X = (569,30)
y = (569,)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(np.asarray(X),np.asarray(y),test_size = 0.25, random_state=0)
```

I am expecting output as below:

- X_train has shape (426, 30)
- X_test has shape (143, 30)
- y_train has shape (426,)
- y_test has shape (143,)

But i am getting the following warning

`ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 1]`

I know that, i can get the desired output in another way, all the problems found in the online show that lengths of X and y are not same but in my case that's not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're misunderstanding what `train_test_split` does. It is not expecting the shapes of the input arrays, what it does is to split the *input arrays* into train and test sets. So you must feed it the actual arrays, for instace:

```
X = np.random.rand(569,30)
y =  np.random.randint(0,2,(569))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(np.asarray(X),np.asarray(y),test_size = 0.25, random_state=0)
```

---

```
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(y_test.shape)

(426, 30)
(143, 30)
(426,)
(143,)
```